# how often does browser geolocation callback fire?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, geolocation, haml, gmaps4rails

I have the following code from gmaps4rails and it constantly makes the map flash in the mobile browser. I was wondeirng how often the `Gmaps.map.geolocationSuccess` callback fires. Is the map flashing in the mobile browser because it's refreshing this callback really often?

```
- content_for :scripts do
  :javascript
    Gmaps.map.geolocationSuccess = function(){
      var lng = Gmaps.map.userLocation.lng();
      var lat = Gmaps.map.userLocation.lat();
      //load map then add the markers
      $('.map_container').hide();
      $('.map_container').show();
      Gmaps.loadMaps();

      //add markers from controller
      Gmaps.map.addMarkers(#{@maps_json});

      var user_image = "http://wiki.alumni.net/wiki/images/thumb/5/55/Wikimap-blue-dot.png/50px-Wikimap-blue-dot.png";

      //add current location marker
      Gmaps.map.addMarkers([{
        "lng": lng,
        "lat": lat,
        "width":"40",
        "height":"48",
        "picture": user_image
      }]);

      //center the screen on your current location
      Gmaps.map.serviceObject.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
      Gmaps.map.serviceObject.setZoom(14);
    };
```

Comment: I guess mobiles track user location somehow. You should simply add a booelan to make the job only once. I should dig browser geolocation a bit more.

Comment: Yeah, how would I make it happen only once?